# Why does this regex fail on a single use case - a text string containing an ampersand?

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to find a regex **to separate out the author and book title** information from a data set.

This one seems to work fine:

```
^\s*(?:(.*)\s+-\s+)?'?([^']+'?.*)\s*$
```

On the data below, **it identifies an author in `group 1`** as the text preceding the first hyphen and, in the case of no hyphen, **it identifies a book title in `group 2`**:

```
William Faulkner - 'Light In August'
William Faulkner - 'Sanctuary'
William Faulkner - 'The Sound and the Fury'
Saki - 'Esme'
Saki - 'The Unrest Cure' (Second Edition)
Saki (File Under: Hector Hugh Munro) - 'The Interlopers' (Anniversary Multi-pack)
William Faulkner - 'The Sound and the Fury' (Collector's Re-issue)
'The Sound and the Fury'
The Sound and the Fury
The Bible (St James Version)
```

**However, in the case of the following string which contains an ampersand, it fails:**

```
'Jim Clarke & Oscar Wilde'
```

Could someone explain why it doesn't work here?

UPDATE:

Here is the relevant Java code:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\s*(?:(.*)\\s+-\\s+)?'?([^']+'?.*)\\s*$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
if(!matcher.matches()) 
{
    logFailure(text);
}
else
{
    String author = matcher.group(1).trim();
    String bookTitle = matcher.group(2).trim();
}
```

A `NullPointerException` is thrown at the following line from the excerpt above:

```
    String author = matcher.group(1).trim();
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce. It works in **Regex Coach**  http://www.weitz.de/regex-coach/

Comment: which language are you using?

Comment: @SilentGhost: I'm using Java where it reads as: "^\\s*(?:(.*)\\s+-\\s+)?'?([^']+'?.*)\\s*$"

Comment: @snoopy: from the regex perspective it's no different from your `'The Sound and the Fury'` example, both match and produce no-matching (empty) group 1 and the full string in group 2 (minus first single quote).

Comment: @SilentGhost: Yes, I downloaded Regex Coach which I didn't know about and it very helpfully highlights the match of groups 1 and group 2. My Java code is failing on the line where I try to get group 1 for this string: `String author = matcher.group(1).trim();`. Now I'm even more confused why it's failing.

Comment: well, I don't know java regex internals, but might it be that `group(1)` is not a string? and therefore `.trim` is failing?

Comment: @SilentGhost: Wow, you may be right. Thanks. Not sure how to check that but I'll take a look.

Comment: @SilentGhost: Actually the regex IS working, as you can see from the Java code that I updated the question with. So there's a good chance you're correct that it's actually failing on the `trim()` call.

Comment: I can't believe it works with some of the other lines like `'The Sound and the Fury'`???!

Comment: I don't think it did, @Carlos.

Comment: @Instantsoup - the question *suggests* that it only fails with the  line `'Jim Clarke & Oscar Wilde'`... (*surely the lack of English knowledge is tricking me*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`matcher.group(1)` is returning null when you don't have a hyphen so `.trim()` is throwing an NPE.

Your current regex also eats the first single quote it finds. Also, do you actually want to not match? You're just logging there. If `text` doesn't actually have to match a pattern, you could use a more simple algorithm.

```
int hyphenIndex = text.indexOf("-");
if (hyphenIndex > -1) {
    String author = text.substring(0, hyphenIndex);
    System.out.println(author);
}
String title = text.substring(hyphenIndex + 1, text.length());
System.out.println(title);
```

However, if you do require rejecting certain strings, there are probably a few things you could do to make this more readable as well.

1. Change the regex to `"^(?:(.*)\\s+-\\s+)?'?([^']+'?.*)$"` and call `pattern.matcher(text.trim())`

Comment: After implementing your regex change in (1.) I end up with a single quote character at the end of the book titles: `The Unrest Cure'`

Comment: Your simpler algorithm makes much more sense for what I'm doing actually. I'm going to use that and forget the regex nonsense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

group(1) can return null, you should check that before trimming

Answer (score 1):

Your Regex works fine, it's just that there is no author in the example you gave, thus the first matching group is null.  So when you try to call matcher.group(1).trim() you get a NPE.

Just handle nulls before you call trim.  Perhaps something like this:

```
String author = matcher.group(1);
if(author == null) {
  author = "";
}
author = author.trim();
```